# Auto-Generating a Schema

Tags: sql, schema

New to Microsoft SQL server Management studio, is there a way to auto generate a schema like the one below, so I can see the all tables and their respective Primary and secondary keys. Thanks :)

[image]

Comment: What version of database?

Comment: SQL Server 2016                                                                     
 Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio      13.0.16106.4

Comment: Sure create a database diagram. Expand the database in object explorer. Then right click on Database Diagrams -> New Database Diagram (select yes if it asks you about creating the requirements). Then you add whatever tables you want and arrange them in whatever layout you want. But be careful, if you do things like delete relationship lines it delete the relationship in the database.